# Running Python processes until first result

Tags: python, multiprocessing

*Edited*
I'm trying to run few Python processes, and want to kill all of them as soon as I get
a result from one of them.
*edit: How do I do that?
In the code below, we can see a loop that initiates 10 processes,

and prints "hello world (i)". How can I stop after the first print?*
I'll put a small example(modified from https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#module-multiprocessing)

```py
# MAIN
from multiprocessing import Process, Lock
import globals
import globalsOperations

globals.init()


def f(l, i):
    # l.acquire()
    # try:
    if not globalsOperations.get_my_bool_state():
        print(globalsOperations.get_my_bool_state())
        print('hello world', i)
        globalsOperations.set_my_bool_state(True)
        print(globalsOperations.get_my_bool_state())


# finally:
#     l.release()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    lock = Lock()

    for num in range(10):
        Process(target=f, args=(lock, num)).start()

# global.py

def init():
    global my_bool
    my_bool = False

#globalsOperations.py
import globals


def set_my_bool_state(bool_value):
    globals.my_bool = bool_value


def get_my_bool_state():
    return globals.my_bool
```

Lock is commented because I've tried to stop after the first success, with no luck.
So- to the question- how do I stop after the first result?
preferably with no memory leaks when releasing the processes..
(I'm not asking a lot of questions here so don't be too harsh on me :) )
thanks!

Comment: You can use `process.terminate()` to end a process... You probably want to assign each process to a variable or array as you start them so you can access and terminate them later.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be anything in your code that's looking for responses from your processes. One thing you could look at is the Value class from multiprocessing.Manager You can use that as a kind of sentinel which a Process can check from time to time (assuming it's running in some kind of loop) to determine if the Process should terminate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your biggest problem is the failure to recognize that each process has its own copy of memory so when one process modifies a global variable the memory spaces of other processes have not been updated. In short, your program cannot possibly work. So `globals` either has to be located in *shared memory* or can be a *managed* object represented by a proxy. I have used the latter since how you would access your global data would require the fewer syntactical changes. This is a *huge* topic. See [this](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html?highlight=namespace#multiprocessing.managers.Namespace).

Second, I would suggest using a multiprocessing pool, e.g. a  `multiprocessing.pool.Pool` instance combined with the `imap_unordered` method rather than individual `multiprocessingProcess` instances. The `imap_unordered` method returns an iterator that you can use to iterate results from your *worker function* `f` as soon as they become available. You need to now modify `f` to return `True` or `False` based upon whether its invocation was the first to set `globals.my_bool` to `True` or not. As soon as the main process gets a `True` result, it can issue method `terminate` on the pool, killing any tasks that are running or scheduled to run.

There will be some lag before the main process detects that a task completed successfully and its termination of the remaining tasks. In that window of time, a few of the other submitted tasks can be running to completion.

Finally, `globals` is a built-in function name and should not be used for other purposes, such as the name of a module or variable. So I will be using the name `gbls` instead.

And you do need to use locking or multiple tasks can think that they are the first to succeed.

There is a lot here for you to be investigating:

```py
from multiprocessing import Manager, Pool, Lock


def init_processes(g, l):
    """
    Initialize the global variable(s) for each process
    in the multiprocessing pool.
    In this case we initialize variable gbls with a proxy to a
    managed Namespace object.
    """
    global gbls, lock
    gbls, lock = g, l

def set_my_bool_state(bool_value):
    gbls.my_bool = bool_value

def get_my_bool_state():
    return gbls.my_bool

def f(i):
    with lock:
        if not get_my_bool_state():
            print(get_my_bool_state())
            print('hello world', i, flush=True)
            set_my_bool_state(True)
            print(get_my_bool_state())
            return True # we were the first to succeed
        else:
            # A few of these might print before the pool is terminated:
            print('Already set.', i, flush=True)
            return False # we were not the first to succeed


if __name__ == '__main__':
    with Manager() as manager:
        gbls = manager.Namespace()
        gbls.my_bool = False
        lock = Lock()
        pool = Pool(10, initializer=init_processes, initargs=(gbls, lock))
        for result in pool.imap_unordered(f, range(10)):
            if result: # first to succeed:
                break
        pool.terminate() # kill all remaining tasks
        # Wait for all processes to end:
        pool.join()
```

Prints:

```
False
hello world 0
True
Already set. 1
Already set. 2
```

Comment: Thanks Booboo. You've helped a lot.
Got me on the right track.

Comment: You could (and should) spend a *long* time studying this line by line with the documentation at your side and if you understand what each line is doing and why and how it was coded as it was, you will have learned a lot. because there is a *lot* going on.

Comment: I agree. This is the first time I'm doing this in python, so I'm still not sure exactly what goes where. It's not exactly `pthread_once` :)